# Why are the two options of my toggle () executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a button with a link, `<a>`, and I want to use it to display or not some elements. For this objective I thought `.toggle()` was a good option.

```js
$('#filter_btn').click(function() {
  $('.filters_container').toggle(function() {
    $(".filters_container").css({
      display: "flex"
    });
  }, function() {
    $(".filters_container").css({
      display: "none"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="filter_btn">Nodes</a>
```

But with this code, when I press the button it shows `filters_container` but immediately they become invisible again. Why is executing both parts of the toggle function?

Thank very much.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of jquerys toggle function I cant find  a way to supply two callbacks to it. .toggle already handles setting display to none for you. There is no need for your to define the toggle behavior using toggle.

https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
$('#filter_btn').click(function() {
   $("p").toggle();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="#" id="filter_btn">Nodes</a>
<p style="display:none">testing</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#filter_btn').click(function() {
   $(".filters_container").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="filter_btn">Nodes</a>
<span class="filters_container" style="display: none;">test</span>
```

simple toggle function use it.

Comment: But the problem of this is that it starts showing, and what I want is start with the hidden option... :/

Answer (score 1):

[This is not how toggle works in jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)

Try to change your code to simply this:

```
$('#filter_btn').click(function() {
  $('.filters_container').toggle();
});
```

Comment: But the problem of this is that it starts showing, and what I want is start with the hidden option... :/

Comment: sorry that wasn't clear from the question. To achieve this you can set `display: none` on the element. Simplest way would be to put `display: none` in `.filters_container` class, but you can also call `$('.filters_container').hide();` when you initialize the element if you prefer